# Can you suspend a Java app and get a snapshot of it's threads from within the app?

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime, monitoring

I'm looking at writing monitoring code that runs inside a Java application and periodically takes a snapshot of running threads and displays some call stack information on each.

Ideally this would be extended for profiling and/or monitoring.

I don't want to use an external tool, as this is for self educational purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Thread.getAllStackTraces()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces())

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to stop all threads (from within the Java byte code).  If you launch the JVM itself using JNI, there _might_ be a way.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `ThreadMXBean.dumpAllThreads(boolean, boolean)`

```
ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
ThreadInfo[] info = bean.dumpAllThreads(true, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the methods of the [Thread](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class such as `Thread.enumerate()`, `Thread.activeCount()`, `Thread.getName()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could register the threads you want to watch at creation time, and have a separate metrics thread to do the monitoring. You would want to build certain metrics into the thread, such as maybe a list of recent running times, current throughput, or other sorts of metrics.

Answer (score 0):

kill -SIGQUIT {java_process}

will dump all stack traces in the stdout of the java process.